# Inserting some text into multiple lines 32 characters before the line ends

Tags: php, regex, notepad++

So I need to add '0', to every line of a 22245 line file, all the values are different so find and replace isn't working, I'm wondering if there's a regex way or something that I can use notepad++ to insert thins 32 characters from the end of each line?

Or maybe a different program or way?  I know a php script would allow me to insert a variable number of spaces from the beginning or the end, but it seems like an unnecessary amount of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using notepad++, you can use a capture group ( `( ... )` ), the end of line anchor (`$`) definite quantifier `{32}` to mean 32 characters, the wildcard `.` and the replace backreference in the replace box like this:

Find:

```
(.{32})$
```

Replace with:

```
0$1
```

Or use a positive lookahead, find:

```
(?=.{32}$)
```

Replace with:

```
0
```

Make sure you have checked the box for regular expression search.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a word / line at a specific line, you can use the following solution. It reads the whole file contents into an array, and use [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/array_splice) to insert the new word into it:

```
// read the file into an array
$lines = file('file.txt');

// set the word and position to be inserted
$wordToBeInserted = 'foo';
$pos = 32; 

// add the word into the array and write it back
array_splice($lines, $pos-1, 0, array("$wordToBeInserted\n"));

// write it back 
file_put_contents('file.txt', implode('', $lines));
```